# heightForRowAt is getting called after cellforRowAt in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Whenever I'm reloading a tableView, `heightForRowAt` is getting called after `cellForRowAt`. The order it is following is:

```
 numberofsections -> numberOfRowsInSection -> cellForRowAt -> heightForRow
```

I have overriden `numberOfSections, numberOfRowsInSection, viewForHeaderInSection` methods. Do these have any effect on order in which `heightForRow` and `cellForRowAt` are called?

I'm using Xcode 9.1, Swift 3 running on iOS 11.

Comment: any change in UI output?

Comment: Can you show more code? I think that you are calling some method in the incorrect place.

Comment: Why do you think thats a problem? Why would OS call `heightForRow` unless you have returned a cell for that row? First cell needs to be created via `cellForRow` and then if you want you can have the height of it adjusted by returning it via `heightForRow`.

Comment: @Ad-J It is a problem. `heightForRow` is always called before `cellForRow`. I've a little complex UI. I'm adding views in cell during runtime. So I need to tell it height before it actually start filling in the values.

Comment: @Mr.Bista I've a little space of 10 units at the end of cell. Since `heightForRow` is being called after `cellForRow`, it is clipping whole cell after a particular height. If `heightForRow` is called before `cellForRow`, which actually should happen, all my issues would be resolved.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to documentation of the order of the calls?

Comment: @crysis - **Your** code determines the height of the cell / row. What are you expecting to get from `heightForRow`? As an aside, if you are dynamically adding elements at runtime, you should be using auto-layout and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` - in which case you skip `heightForRow` completely.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Make contentView of the cell in the way it will define it's size. It means that your layout shouldn't be ambitious vertically.
2. Calculate it's size manually. Sum up offsets (heights) between (of) subviews. Here may be a problem to calculate label / textView size (leave helper extension for calculating text size which I use). Pay attention on textView.contentInsets! You need to keep it mind too to get correct size

   ```
   extension String {
        func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
            let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
            let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                   attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

            return ceil(boundingBox.height)
        }

        func width(withConstraintedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
            let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
            let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                   attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

            return ceil(boundingBox.width)
        }
   }
   ```

Hope it will help you!